# Ehcache( Unable to load Class)

Tags: ehcache, ehcache-bigmemory

Hi All i am facing the issue in which i m not able to load my ehcache.xml file & its giving me error as below

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Unable to load class net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.ExpressEnterpriseTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory. Initial cause was org.terracotta.toolkit.ToolkitInstantiationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create toolkit.
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.ClassLoaderUtil.createNewInstance(ClassLoaderUtil.java:90)
    at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.TerracottaClusteredInstanceHelper.newClusteredInstanceFactory(TerracottaClusteredInstanceHelper.java:157)
    at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.TerracottaClient.createNewClusteredInstanceFactory(TerracottaClient.java:180)
    at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.TerracottaClient.createClusteredInstanceFactory(TerracottaClient.java:129)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:463)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:395)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:270)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1116)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:947)
    at BigMemoryDemo.main(BigMemoryDemo.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.terracotta.toolkit.ToolkitInstantiationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create toolkit.
    at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.TerracottaToolkitBuilder.createToolkit(TerracottaToolkitBuilder.java:63)
    at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.TerracottaToolkitBuilder.buildToolkit(TerracottaToolkitBuilder.java:56)
    at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.ToolkitInstanceFactoryImpl.createTerracottaToolkit(ToolkitInstanceFactoryImpl.java:183)
    at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.ToolkitInstanceFactoryImpl.<init>(ToolkitInstanceFactoryImpl.java:119)
    at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.ToolkitInstanceFactoryImpl.<init>(ToolkitInstanceFactoryImpl.java:129)
    at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.EnterpriseToolkitInstanceFactory.<init>(EnterpriseToolkitInstanceFactory.java:23)
    at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.store.EnterpriseTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.createToolkitInstanceFactory(EnterpriseTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.java:21)
    at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.store.TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.<init>(TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.java:65)
    at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.store.EnterpriseTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.<init>(EnterpriseTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.java:15)
    at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.ExpressEnterpriseTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.<init>(ExpressEnterpriseTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.ClassLoaderUtil.createNewInstance(ClassLoaderUtil.java:73)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.terracotta.toolkit.ToolkitInstantiationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create toolkit.
    at com.terracotta.toolkit.api.TerracottaToolkitFactoryService.createToolkit(TerracottaToolkitFactoryService.java:49)
    at org.terracotta.toolkit.ToolkitFactory.create(ToolkitFactory.java:100)
    at org.terracotta.toolkit.ToolkitFactory.createToolkit(ToolkitFactory.java:84)
    at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.TerracottaToolkitBuilder.createToolkit(TerracottaToolkitBuilder.java:61)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create toolkit.
    at com.terracotta.toolkit.client.TerracottaToolkitCreator.createToolkit(TerracottaToolkitCreator.java:70)
    at com.terracotta.toolkit.api.EnterpriseTerracottaToolkitFactoryService.createToolkit(EnterpriseTerracottaToolkitFactoryService.java:17)
    at com.terracotta.toolkit.api.TerracottaToolkitFactoryService.createToolkit(TerracottaToolkitFactoryService.java:44)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.terracotta.toolkit.ToolkitRuntimeException: net.sf.ehcache.config.InvalidConfigurationException: The disk path for this cache manager is the default path. You must define a specific unique disk path for this manager in order to use restartable caches.
    at com.terracotta.toolkit.client.TerracottaToolkitCreator.initializeDefaultCacheManagerProvider(TerracottaToolkitCreator.java:175)
    at com.terracotta.toolkit.client.TerracottaToolkitCreator.createToolkit(TerracottaToolkitCreator.java:55)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.terracotta.toolkit.ToolkitRuntimeException: net.sf.ehcache.config.InvalidConfigurationException: The disk path for this cache manager is the default path. You must define a specific unique disk path for this manager in order to use restartable caches.
    at com.terracotta.toolkit.express.TerracottaInternalClientImpl.instantiate(TerracottaInternalClientImpl.java:159)
    at com.terracotta.toolkit.client.TerracottaToolkitCreator.initializeDefaultCacheManagerProvider(TerracottaToolkitCreator.java:173)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.config.InvalidConfigurationException: The disk path for this cache manager is the default path. You must define a specific unique disk path for this manager in order to use restartable caches.
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.restartability.EhcacheRestartability.constructRestartability(EhcacheRestartability.java:189)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.restartability.EhcacheRestartability.startup(EhcacheRestartability.java:94)
    at net.sf.ehcache.EnterpriseFeaturesManager.startup(EnterpriseFeaturesManager.java:102)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:520)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:395)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:270)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1116)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1092)
    at com.terracotta.toolkit.ToolkitCacheManagerProvider.createDefaultToolkitCacheManager(ToolkitCacheManagerProvider.java:19)
    at com.terracotta.toolkit.ToolkitCacheManagerProvider.<init>(ToolkitCacheManagerProvider.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.terracotta.toolkit.express.TerracottaInternalClientImpl.instantiate(TerracottaInternalClientImpl.java:156)
    ... 30 more
```

Note:- It was working fine earlier. I just made one more passive node at TSA. TSA is up & running

This is ehcache.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" 
         name="BigMemoryMax">
         <defaultCache         
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="0"/> 
        <cache name="PersonCache" maxEntriesLocalHeap="20">

        <searchable/>

        </cache>
        <terracottaConfig url="127.0.0.1:9510" />
</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact error is at the bottom of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.config.InvalidConfigurationException: The disk path for this cache manager is the default path. You must define a specific unique disk path for this manager in order to use restartable caches.
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.restartability.EhcacheRestartability.constructRestartability(EhcacheRestartability.java:189)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.restartability.EhcacheRestartability.startup(EhcacheRestartability.java:94)
    at net.sf.ehcache.EnterpriseFeaturesManager.startup(EnterpriseFeaturesManager.java:102)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:520)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:395)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:270)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1116)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1092)
```

This indicates a configuration issue and given that the configuration you give in your question has no disk component, it means that your application is loading a different `ehcache.xml`.

Normally Ehcache indicates in its logs which configuration file is loaded. If you do not see that, turn logging level to `DEBUG` for `net.sf.ehcache` in your logging framework.

Comment: Yes @Louis. Thanks for reply. Yes it was loading a different Configuration..In Disk Path i earlier used "java.io.tmpdir". After that i removed it since then it was giving problem  even after giving diff path.          So i removed all the temp folder data in machine as soon as i did that.. it started working fine......Thanks a lot